# How to Work with Dynamic Multidimensional Array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have dynamic multidimensional array like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => index.php
    [src] => Array
        (
            [src2] => Array
                (
                    [src3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test_src3.php
                        )

                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test_src2.php
                        )

                )

            [0] => test_src.php
        )

    [src_test] => Array
        (
            [New Folder] => Array
                (
                )

            [src_test2] => Array
                (
                    [New Folder] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [src_test3] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

      [1] => test.php
)
```

The number of dimensions might be change based on sub directories that found in a folder path inputted by user (this program is used by a person in their local).

How could i fetch those array elements so that the result would be like this :

```
array(
    [0] => src/src2/src3
    [1] => src_test/New Folder
    [2] => src_test/src_test2/New Folder/
    [3] => src_test/src_test2/src_test3
)
```

By the way i have a function to achieve this :

```
function getKeyPaths(array $tree, $glue = '/'){
        $paths = array();
        foreach ($tree as $key => &$mixed) {
            if (is_array($mixed)) {
                $results = getKeyPaths($mixed, $glue);
                foreach ($results as $k => &$v) {
                    $paths[$key . $glue . $k] = $v;
                }
                unset($results);
            } else {
                $paths[$key] = $mixed;
            }
        }

        return $paths;
    }
```

the above function does not result like what i expected:

```
Array
(
    [0] => index.php
    [src/src2/src3/0] => test_src3.php
    [src/src2/0/0] => test_src2.php
    [src/0] => test_src.php
)
```

How do i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

One approach :

```
function getKeyPaths(array $tree, $glue = '/', $return_array = true){
        $paths = "";
        foreach ($tree as $key => &$mixed) {
            $path = $key . $glue;
            if (is_array($mixed) && !is_int($key) ) {
                $paths .= $path . getKeyPaths( $mixed, $glue, false);
                if ($return_array) {
                    $paths .= "|";
                }
            }
        }
        if ($return_array) {
            return explode("|", trim($paths, "|"));
        }
        return $paths;
}
```

Comment: You are actually right sir. I am sorry i have give worng result, i am really sorry.
I actually expect the results like this :
`array(
    [0] => src/src2/src3
    [1] => src_test/New Folder
    [2] => src_test/src_test2/New Folder/
    [3] => src_test/src_test2/src_test3
)`.
I am really sorry.
Can you give me another approach ?

Comment: I am sorry, i have given wrong result information to be.